# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/Golcha/Desktop/Automation/geckodriver.exe

Tags: java, exception, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Getting the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist:
>   /Users/Golcha/Desktop/Automation/geckodriver.exe

**Code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class selenium{

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[]args){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","Users/Golcha/Desktop/Automation/geckodriver.exe");

        setDriver(new FirefoxDriver());
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public static void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        selenium.driver = driver;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not add the whole error message in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code but check the path of `geckodriver` properly before executing the below code or I ll suggest you to paste `geckodriver` in `C` drive or any other drives to make your path simple as below one :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
```

It should work without any problem .  All the best !

Comment: Thank you so much..its working now when i edited the portion to this webdriver.firefox.marionette

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have not mentioned the complete(full) path for the Geckodriver in your ***System.setProperty()*** method. you have missed the drive letter ***"C"***

> "C:/Users/Golcha/Desktop/Automation/geckodriver.exe"

Let me know if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but weirdly I was not able to execute the selenium script on both my drivers (chrome and firefox), I tried checking my `setProperty` method, my gecko driver path and chrome driver path. Lastly, I tried updating both my browser and it seems to be working now. (my current version of Chrome is 66 and my current version of my Firefox is 56.0).